# How to get the profile name associated to the login username in Win10 C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

So, currently I get the login credential (username) with this line:

```
Environment.UserName
```

But what I want is to get the name which appears in Settings -> Accounts -> Your Info (Windows 10). Basically it's the name of the profile from the windows associated to that user that is logged in.
Any thoughts please?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Amy, but I was looking for a more specific object, WindowsIdentity is pretty general. You can have a look at Tom's answer.

Comment: You said "any thoughts".  If you wanted something specific, maybe you should say so in the question?

Comment: I appreciate your kind thought, Amy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use `DisplayName`?

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```

More information can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Tom!
PS. Be aware that proper references must be added to the project.

Comment: No worries Marko, you are correct, you do need to added the references sorry I should of put this in my answer :).